# append a html file to div created by a js script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an HTML file to a div recent created by a js script but I get an error in the jquery library,

the code here, create a div and I want to append room.html within :

```
var contenedor = $('PageLoaded');
$('#button').click(function(){
    container = document.createElement('<div></div>');
    container.setAttribute('class','container');
    container.get("room.html", function(htmlexterno){
       $(".container").html(htmlexterno);
    });
```

How can I embed room.html into the div which I am creating?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

You seem a little confused about the difference between native JS and jQuery methods.

`container` is an Element object. It has no `get()` method as that's part of jQuery. To fix this you could use `$.get()` instead.

However, given your usage, it would appear that `$.load()` is more appropriate here as your goal is to add content to the new element.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  let $container = $('<div class="container"></div>').appendTo('#yourSelectorHere...');
  $container.load("room.html");
});
```